# How to print on both sides (Duplex printing) using HP ePrint 

Tags: printing, printer, network-printer, hp-laserjet, duplex

I am using HP LaserJet Professional P1606dn. I just started using HP ePrint, and I don't know how print on both sides of the paper using the HP ePrint. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [HP Customer Care -> Getting Started with ePrint for HP LaserJet Pro P1606dn Printer:](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c03128535&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=4110410&tmp_track_link=ot_search#N1144)

```
Q: Are there any limitations that I should be aware of when using ePrint?

A: Duplexing (printing on both sides of the page) is not supported.
```

However, there is currently one way to duplex print using ePrint - if you're using ePrint from a computer (not a mobile device), you can install the [ePrint Print Mobile Driver](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?prodNameId=5098101&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=135&prodSeriesId=5098100&prodTypeId=22744). This allows you to duplex print (printing on both sides of the page) using ePrint. Keep in mind that it is only possible when printing from a computer.

Comment: Hi, I want to using Google Cloud Print -> ePrint -> HP printer to print both sides. Any way ?

Comment: If you're printing from a computer, then it's possible (see instructions in my answer) - I believe the Google Cloud Print is no different than the regular "Word" Print for example, regarding the use of the printer driver & software (ePrint). [Take a look at this page for more information](http://www.hp.com/global/us/en/eprint/google-cloud-print.html?re_r11400_campaigns_eprint_google_cloud_print_redirect). If you're printing from a mobile device, then the answer is no, it's not possible.